# Enforce what is passed to an activity in an intent similar to the newInstance pattern for fragments

Tags: java, android, factory-method

For fragments I have this code to create a new instance:

```
public static FoodDetails newInstance(Food food) {
    FoodDetails foodDetails = new FoodDetails();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable(FoodConstants.BundleConstants.FOOD_OBJECT, food);
    foodDetails .setArguments(args);
    return foodDetails ;
}
```

What I like about this is that I can see what arguments are passed to the fragment.

I want a similar way for `Activities` so this is my proposed solution.

```
public class FullScreenImageActivity extends BaseActivity {

public static Intent createIntent(String[] images, String googleAnalyticsCategory,int positionToStartFrom){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyApplication.getInstance(),FullScreenImageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(FoodConstants.BundleConstants.LIST_OF_IMAGES_TO_DISPLAY,images);
    intent.putExtra(FoodConstants.BundleConstants.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CATEGORY,googleAnalyticsCategory);
    intent.putExtra(FoodConstants.BundleConstants.POSITION_TO_START_FROM, positionToStartFrom);
    return intent;
}
```

The method returns a built intent and adds the parameters to the bundle
Note that `MyApplication` is a subclass of `Application` so I am using the application context in the intent argument.

And then you can start the activity like this:

```
startActivity(FullScreenImageActivity.createIntent(mImages, AnalyticsUtils.CATEGORY_FOOD,position));
```

The benefits are:

- Do not need type the bundle keys all the time
- You can see what arguments are passed to the activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution looks great to me, apply `Fragment`'s instantation to a `Class` seems to be a good pattern and a nice idea. However, I have just a little tip for this static method: pass the current `Context` instead of `Application Context`:

```
public class SampleActivity extends BaseActivity {
    public static Intent createIntent(Context context, String[] a, String b) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEY_ARG_ARRAY,  a);
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEY_ARG_STRING, b);
        return intent;
    }
}
```

This allows you to get the right `Activity` calling the new `Intent` instead of whole application context. So, the called syntax could be:

```
startActivity( SampleActivity.createIntent(this, a, b) );
// 'this' being the calling class Context (like 'MainActivity.this' or 'getActivity()')
```